# Error 404 updating Note Edge to 6.0

Tags: ota-update, samsung-galaxy-note, verizon

My Verizon note edge is stock, not rooted or unlocked. I initiated an ota update and it failed. Here is the error.

[image]

Comment: if that's an HTTP error (which is very likely, as it wants to download a file), the file cannot be found. Most likely reasons: Between you receiving the update notice and pressing the button to finally do it, the file was removed (e.g. due to some trouble it caused on other devices). I'd suggest wait a few days for a new update notice, then try again.

Comment: For the record it does fully download the update and reboot into recovery.  The little android with his front open starts spinning and then he dies and it just says "Error!".  I get the error in the screenshot on reboot.

Comment: In that case: no idea, sorry.

Comment: I found some forums where people had luck disabling auto time update (?) or clearing the cache, none of which have worked for me.  I'm trying Samsung Keys/Smart Switch right now.  Next step will be factory reset then try again.